How to copy multiple images to clipboard
I wonder if its possible to copy multiple images to the clipboard in Java AWT/Swing?
I saw a solution in JavaFX, but can't use it. Or if you have a solution to use the JavaFX function in an AWT program, I'll take it
I've tried and have this error:

This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread =
AWT-EventQueue-0

I actually have multiple JFreeChart on one panel and want to copy all of them at once.
So I run through all my graphs and do this
for(JFreeChart plot : test) {
    BufferedImage objBufferedImage = plot.getChart().createBufferedImage(600, 800);
    ImageTransferable transferable = new ImageTransferable(objBufferedImage);
    clipboard.setContents(transferable, null);
}

with ImageTranferable is the classic static class :
static class ImageTransferable implements Transferable {
    private Image image;

    public ImageTransferable(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
        if (isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
            return image;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavor == DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.imageFlavor };
    }
}

As you can suppose only the last chart is copied.
How can I copy all images at once?
I don't want to concatenate because I want to use them separately after the paste (same behavior as Microsoft Word when you copy multiple images).
EDIT :
I've found a way to use the clipboard of JavaFX in AWT/Swing and copy multiple images at once.
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 javafx.scene.input.Clipboard clipboard = javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
                 ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    
                 List<File> listFiles = new ArrayList<>();
                 for(JFreeChart plot : test) {
                     BufferedImage objBufferedImage=plot.getChart().createBufferedImage(plot.getSize().width, plot.getSize().height);
                     File outputfile = new File(plot.getTitle() + ".png");
                     try {
                         ImageIO.write(objBufferedImage, "png", outputfile);
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                                
                     listFiles.add(outputfile);
                 }
                 content.putFiles(listFiles);
                 clipboard.setContent(content);
            }
       });
    } 
});


This question is similar to: Multiple objects to clipboard. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is this will reopened since this is not the same case ?

Only if you rewrite your post so that it's clear that it really is a different issue, because your question in your post is "[is it] possible to copy multiple images to the clipboard in Java AWT/Swing" to which the answer is "yes, see the already mentioned post".

Actually in the mentioned post it work for JavaFX not AWT/Swing. Or am I missing something ?

Then please update your "I saw a solution in JavaFX, but can't use it. " to link to what solution you saw, and explain why you can't use that (because imports don't care about the name of the import, and the clipboard has nothing to do with your UI). Also, answers can use an "edit: ..." section, if the answer changes because time passed and technologies change, but questions should never have that: just update your post while keeping it a normal text. Someone who hadn't seen  your post before doesn't need to know it has an edit history =)
